# wordpress 4.7.3 reload same page

Tags: wordpress, caching

i'm trying to fix a strange issue of my website.
I use latest wordpress version with woocommerce and wootheme.
I really don't know when it started that problem.

The problem is very simple, when i am in backend often i can't change page, i can click everywhere but reloads the same page.

For example if i am in Posts>Example1 and i want to go to Pages i click on it, i see "?post_type=page" but reloads Example1! is very frustrating because to change page i need to wait many secs or mins.. like a cache problem but i disabled all plugin cache!

If i hold 30 secs and i click the page loads correctly.

Sometimes that same problem appears in website, not only in backend.
For example I tried to add a product to cart, after adding I put it back and the problem recurred, the page is reloaded and the product was always there, I had to clear the cache manually (Ctrl + F5) and then worked.

Comment: Did you tried deactivating the current active theme and put default one?

Comment: Yes, i tried, same problem.